# How to set Column width to the longest of its children say Row?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have column that all its children are rows of words (text widget) that each row have main alignment of MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween. i want to set the width of the column to the longest row between the children and that the other rows will change the space between accordingly.

my code:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.green,
  child: Column(
  children: [
    Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text('A', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4), 
        Text('B', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
        Text('C', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4)
      ]),
     Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text('A', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4), 
        Text('B', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
        Text('C', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
        Text('D', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
        Text('E', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4),
      ]),
  ]))
```

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result: [image]

how can I set the column width (dynamically) to the longest row assuming I cant set it in the container as fixed width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` in `IntrinsicWidth`:

```
IntrinsicWidth(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Row(...),
      Row(...),
    ],
  ),
)
```